# Apply script build.gradle error when adding firebase dependencies to an android app

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, firebase-realtime-database

I am adding firebase to my android application. After adding dependecies  `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'` and implementation `'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.1'` and plugins that is apply `plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` and trying to sync it brings an "Apply script build.gradle" error

I have updated my google repositories and have a good internet connection

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' 

dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.2.1'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'}`
dependencies{implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.1'}
```

I expected a successful sync after adding the dependencies and applying plugins but an error occured

Answer (score 1):

Check [the doc:](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin#adding_the_json_file)

To setup firebase you have to configure the **top-level** `build.gradle` file with:

```
buildscript {

  repositories {
    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
  }

  dependencies {
    // ...

    // Add the following line:
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'  // Google Services plugin
  }
}

allprojects {
  // ...

  repositories {
    // Check that you have the following line (if not, add it):
    google()  // Google's Maven repository
    // ...
  }
}
```

Then in your `app/build.gradle` :

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
  // ...
}

dependencies {
  // ...
  implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.1'

}

// Add the following line to the bottom of the file:
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'  // Google Play services Gradle plugin
```

To complete the [setup of the google play services plugin](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) you have to

- add the `google-services.json` file.

Answer (score 0):

> For Latest android studio, you can add library like below

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '7.2.0' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.6.21' apply false
    id 'com.google.dagger.hilt.android' version '2.43.2' apply false
    id 'androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin' version '2.4.1' apply false

    
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services' version '4.3.10' apply false 
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics' version '2.8.1' apply false
}
```

**settings.gradle**

```
pluginManagement {
    repositories {
        gradlePluginPortal()
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
dependencyResolutionManagement {
    repositoriesMode.set(RepositoriesMode.FAIL_ON_PROJECT_REPOS)
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}
rootProject.name = "GameShow"
```